# Finding element based on multiple sub elements

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

The page has multiple questions/answers sets on it.  Each set is grouped into a div of class 'questionItem'.  In each set there is always an input named answers[idx].SetAnser and there might be a answers[idx].Answer, where idx is the index of the set.

The problem which needs to be solved is finding all the question set div elements where SetAnswer is of one value and Answer is of another value.  Here is the sample html:

```
<div class="questionItem format">
    <input name="answers[0].SetAnswer" type="hidden" value="0" />

    <select name="answers[0].Answer">
      <option selected="selected" value="0">(0) No</option>
      <option value="1">(1) Yes</option>
      <option value="-">(-) Not assessed</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div class="questionItem format">
    <input name="answers[1].SetAnswer" type="hidden" value="?" />
    <select name="answers[1].Answer">
        <option selected="selected" value="?">(select item)</option>
        <option value="0">(0) No</option>
        <option value="1">(1) Yes</option>
        <option value="-">(-) Not assessed</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div class="questionItem format">
    <input name="answers[2].SetAnswer" type="hidden" value="?" />
    <input name="answers[2].Answer" type="number" value="" />    
</div>

<div class="questionItem format">
    <input name="answers[3].SetAnswer" type="hidden" value="red" />
    <input name="answers[3].Answer" type="number" value="red" />    
</div>
```

The best I have been able to come up with, which is not working is something like this:

```
var answerColl = $(this).find(":input").filter(function () {
    return /^answers\[\d+\]\.Answer$/.test(this.name); 
    });

// Make sure there is an 'Answer' input, if there isn't, that is because it is 
// not displayed, so assume not unanswered
if (answerColl.length > 0) {
    var answerElement = answerColl.first();
    var answer = answerElement.value;

    // First check to see if the answer is ?
    if (answer == "?")
        return true;

    // Next check to see if the answer is empty, if so, must check the setAnswer.  
    // If the setAnswer is ^, then this is no unanswered, if it is ? it is unanswered.
    if (!Boolean(answer)) {

        var setAnswerElement = $(this).find(":input").filter(function () { return /^answers\[\d+\]\.SetAnswer$/.test(this.name); }).first();
        var setAnswer = setAnswerElement.value;

        if (setAnswer == "?")
            return true;
    }
}

return false;
```

the issue is in:

```
var answerElement = answerColl.first();
var answer = answerElement.value;
```

When I look at it in a debugger, answerElement is a jQuery object, but answer is always null.  When looking at answerElement the default value is the value I am seeking, the actual answer, but I cannot figure out how to get at that in the code.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `value` is plain javascript, you need to use `val()` with jQuery objects.

Comment: @adeneo You should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to write up a Regex expression for this.. you can easily solve this just by using a $.each loop..
First select the elements .. Then run the $.each loop on those elements to check for the condition you stated.. Try this

```
$(function() {

    $('#btn1').on('click', function() {
        var correctAnswer = $('.questionItem input');
        var userAnswer = $('.questionItem select option:selected');

        $.each(correctAnswer, function(i) {
            // This will give the Question Div's Whose SetAnswer and Answers are different..
            if ($(this).val() != $(userAnswer[i]).val()) {

                // Will give a List of all Answers that are set
                console.log('Correct Answer for Question ' + i + ' is  : ' + $(this).val());
                // Will give a List of all Answers that the user Answered
                console.log('User Selection for Question ' + i + ' is  : ' + $(userAnswer[i]).val());

                // This will print the Question Div for Which 
                // SetAnswer and Answer is different..
                console.log('SetAnswer is of one value and Answer is of another value for : ' + $(this).parent().attr('id'));
            }
        });
    });

});​
```

Check this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/txn2D/) for a working example..